# Submitting value of checkbox in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox, submit

I am new to php and I am trying to implement a code to put checkboxes in a table and add data submitted by those checkboxes in database. Following is my code to create checkboxes inside a loop in php:-

```
$i=0;
$i++;
$transcript = $DB->get_field('course_completions', 'Transcript', array ('course'=>$course->id, 'userid'=>$this->user->id), $strictness=IGNORE_MISSING);
if($transcript==0){
    $checked="";
}
else{
    $checked='checked';
}
$check = '<input type="checkbox" name="tanscript'.$i.'" value=0 '.$checked.' />';
$data = array($check, $year, $sem, $courselink, $coursefullname, $type, $max_credits, $grade, $points);
```

The $data array is used to display data in table.
The $transcript is used to retrieve values from database and determine whether the checkbox should be checked by default or not.

Can someone tell me how to enter the data that has checked in the checkboxes in the database without using submit button? Also, how do I input the new values in database if someone unchecks the boxes again?

Comment: Google? http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Comment: In order to send information from the client side to the server side you should either use AJAX or submit a from like arxanas suggested.

Comment: Oh. I cannot use the subit button directly which is why I asked the question. Sorry. Should have mentioned that in my question. I'll read up on AJAX and check how this can be done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default (?) **value** is set to 'on' when $checked otherwise is set to 'off'

Answer (score 0):

you may create **checked** checkbox by giving `checked="checked"` to your checkbox. You can implement this via a variable like;

```
if($something == $data){
  $check = 'checked="checked"';
}else{
  $check = '';
}
```

and you may implement this in your checkbox like;

```
echo '<input type="checkbox"'.$check.'value="somevalue">'
```

also you may use a `<form>` using either `GET` or `POST` method to pass the value into DB. For example, you may try this in your form;

'

and in your `processor.php` you may grab data like
$checkbox_value = $_POST["chkbox"];

and you may use `if - else` for `$checkbox_value` to check if there is value or not.